# Setup auth on EC2 Ubuntu MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up auth on an instance of a MongoDB server on EC2 ubuntu

When auth = true is commented out works fine:
mongod.conf if #auth = true
mongo admin -u myusername -p mypassword

Fails:
if mongod.conf auth = true
mongo admin -u myusername -p mypassword
connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer this question, auth = true is for older version of mongo 2.4
I was using mongo 3.4 so instead of setting auth = true set 
security:
   authorization: enabled

Answer (score 0):

When you comment it out, MongoDB will run with no auth enabled on that instance, this is for maintenance. If you connect to it via the shell and it has previously had auth enabled it will give you a warning.

What is the error that you're getting when it refuses to connect?

try resetting the password or adding in another user when auth is disabled.